# Is a GM meant to compel when the player has no Fate Points Remaining?

Tags: fate, dresden-files, compels

So we tried out the Dresden Files RPG earlier.  Overall, we had a great time.  Some issues came up, though.  Specifically, when you compel an aspect, the player has the choice to either accept the compel (gain a fate point) or spend a fate point to ignore the compel.  What if the player has no fate points remaining?  At that point, it feels cheesy to compel, as the GM winds up effectively railroading the character, frequently at a plot critical point.  Is that the intention?  Is this the risk you run when you spend your last fate point?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Yes**, that is exactly the risk a character runs when they run out of fate points.  Fate points represent a character's ability to modify... fate, or their free will.  IF they don't have any fate points then they are locked into doing what their core character would do.  This is the same as being an npc with 0 or less refresh, you are bound by your nature.

It may seem unfair for a GM to compel a character with no fate points, but the flip side is that the character now has a fate point to determine the outcome of a future situation.

Answer (score 9):

A character out of fate is unable to reject a compel. He MUST accept it. Which will, of course, give him one to spend. But being that low should be rare.

A GM should not be limiting his compels to when a character is out of Fate Points. He should be offering compels any time the narrative makes them make sense.

Nor should the GM compel just because a player is out of Fate.

Compels should always and only be used when it makes either good story sense or good drama to do so.

Really, players should not be running out very often. If they are, you as a GM need to compel more during game, and work those aspects of theirs. If you are already working them a lot, then the players need to get over themselves and start accepting some. It's a balancing act... but so long as you're using compels that make sense in story, they should be fine.

Comment: I've found that wizards in the Dresden Files run out of them more often than in other FATE games (starting with 1 will do that for you).

Comment: And don't forget that players can compel **themselves**, too.

Comment: @wraith808 is right, and that's how it's supposed to work.  Powerful supernatural characters come with a host of social and practical problems, or in game terms: they'll have to accept a lot of compels before they're ready for major trouble.

Comment: @gomad there really isn't such a thing as a self-compel.  It works out that way, but self-compels *really* are reminders for the GM.  Hopefully as the GM gets more familiar with the characters and their aspects, self-compels become less of a problem, because the GM becomes more able to keep track of the PCs.

Comment: @wraith808 - I beg to differ. Not only is it specifically mentioned in the books that you can self-compel, I think it's important for players to be looking for chances to fulfill their Aspects, and the Fate point is the reward for doing just that. If the GM says, "I'll give you a Fate point if you <blank>," that's a GM compel. If the player says, "I'll <blank> if you give me a Fate point," that's a self compel. I think it's part of the FATE ethos to distribute narrative control in that fashion.

Comment: @gomad - reference?  I know I've seen Fred Hicks has said it isn't really a mechanic per say before, and even in the Dresden Files RPG `YW100` it puts it in quotes to indicate it is a term, not a mechanic.

Comment: @wraith808 - It's in the DFRPG books that I most recently remember seeing it, but I swear it was in SotC too. As to whether it's in quotes or not, I can't recall. But why should the GM, who is in charge of the vast majority of the universe, also be responsible for the PCs, whose players have everything they need to know about the characters right in front of them on the sheet, as well as being concerned pretty much with just that character? Mechanic or not, self-compels constitute good play.

Comment: @gomad I wasn't trying to imply that it was bad play, that's why they have the one reference to it.  It just becomes less necessary over time, in my experience.  And yes, the GM should be intimately familiar with the characters in his verse, especially since the stories and game should revolve around them, instead of the vast majority of the universe in my opinion.  But that's a different question :)

Comment: @wraith808 - Yes, absolutely - the GM should be that familiar with the PCs. But the **actions** of the main characters is pretty much entirely the purview of the players, not the GM. So why shouldn't volunteering to take a potentially-trouble-making action in exchange for a meta-point in accordance with a per-established Aspect of theirs be just plain part of the game? I don't want you to get the feeling I'm arguing with you - I think we're agreeing on the major points of this issue with increasing zest. Which is sometimes mistaken for argument!

Comment: @gomad self-compelling is NOT in SOTC. Page 44 has "The GM performs compels;
when she compels someone’s aspect, she’s indicating that the character
is in a position where the aspect could create a problem. However, players
can cause the GM to compel another character’s aspects, via tagging, with
a similar rationale and results (see “Tagging for Effect”, above)." Might be in DF.